# How do data analysts set up their work environment, or how to work under Linux but write with MS word?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, ms-office

I am PhD student, most of my work is related to statistical analysis of large amount of data ( binary files). I recently bought a new desktop, I am looking for suggestions for setting up my desktop. I have some considerations:

1. Most of my work must be done on Linux platform.
2. My supervisor uses MS windows only, and he requires us to write reports in MS word/PPT so that he can make comment easily.
3. Beside desktops, we have a cluster computer whose OS is RHEL. It stores the data to be analyzed.

Now the problem is that if I install Linux only on my desktop, then I can't write reports. If I install both in my desktop, I have to switch back and forth which is fussy. And I cannot access my data that stored under Linux file system. If I use windows only, then I can't work! Three solutions are in my mind

1. Buy another laptop, use desktop for data analysis and the laptop for report writing. All my collages adopt this solution. But still, it is fussy because I have to have top displays on my tiny desk, and in addition it is inconvenient to download and upload data to and fro between two computers.
2. Install Linux only and use virtual machine to simulate a windows, I really want to try this solution, but I don't have any experiences. Are virtual machine softwares on Linux platform stable or are they just as messy as wine?

Are there any other solutions to my situation?

Comment: MAybe you could convince your supervisor to use LaTeX which is very widely used in academia?

Comment: And LaTeX gives you very nice looking equations (IMHO nicer than what Word can produce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox works well for running Windows under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

```
he requires us to write reports in MS word
[...]
Now the problem is that if I install Linux only on my desktop, then I can't 
write reports.
```

With
[LibreOffice Writer](http://libreoffice.org/features/writer),
you can save as Microsoft Word format.

> Writer easily reads Microsoft Word documents, and you can also save your 
>   work in Microsoft Word format, for sending to people still locked into 
>   Microsoft products.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that LibreOffice cannot display or edit equations of MS Word documents properly. And vice versa